# Sigsegv when creating channel - possible cert error?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running through the samples to create my own blockchain dev environment - https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/installing/development-tools.html

However, then the startfabric script fails because I get a sigsev when running the command - docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx

There is a fabric bug reported late 2017 that discusses something similar around certificates being out of date.

I think the channel is created but I don't have a genesis file returned/created on my peer (is that what's supposed to happen when I create/join a channel). So, is there a way to join the channel with this bug or what else do i have to do please?

2018-02-28 14:07:11.067 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 018 Obtaining default signing identity
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7fcd514a1259]

many thanks
john.

Comment: Similar SIGSEGV errors reported here https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5822 and https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6970 and https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2539?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: A few details might help: which version of Fabric, which operating system, which Docker version and which hardware platform / CPU?  Also, is there anything else in the stack trace?

Comment: am having a similar problem, how did you solve it

Answer (score 2):

I had the  same issue and this is how I fixed. Add `GODEBUG=netdns=go` to the environment variables of peer, orderer, and cli inside the docker compose yaml files. A more detailed explanation can be got from this [site](https://yq.aliyun.com/articles/238940). This is how the environemental variable should look like.

```
 peer-base:
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - GODEBUG=netdns=go 
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # bridge network as the peers
  # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
  #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: peer node start
```