# unexpected signal during runtime execution [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation ..] when creating channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

am getting the following error when creating a channel, a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032172/sigsegv-when-creating-channel-possible-cert-error) has been asked but no answer was provided. Am using the fabric samples (`git clone -b issue-6978 https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples.git)`   Previously I never hard this problem untill when I restarted my machine. Am using ubuntu 18.04
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem, I added  `GODEBUG=netdns=go` to the environment variables of peer, orderer, and cli inside the docker compose yaml files. A more detailed explanation can be got from this [site](https://yq.aliyun.com/articles/238940). This is how the environemental variable should look like.

```
 peer-base:
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - GODEBUG=netdns=go 
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # bridge network as the peers
  # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
  #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: peer node start
```